# Left-Align Table in Beamer Presentation

Tags: tables, beamer, horizontal-alignment, presentations

I have a table within a frame in a presentation using the beamer package, and it's centered in the frame right now:

```
\subsection{Results}
\begin{frame}{Results}
\begin{table} 
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l}
six & things & to & fill & the & space \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table Caption}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
```

I'm looking to shift it to the left of the frame and put two graph figures on the right stacked on top of one another. How would I set this up as a frame?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I use to have two columns on a beamer slide. This is just a workaround to your problem. You may want to adapt the distances in the `column` environment as well as the `c` for centering.

```
\subsection{Results}
\begin{frame}{Results}
\begin{columns}[c]
    \begin{column}{5cm}
         \begin{table} 
         \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l}
             six & things & to & fill & the & space \\
         \end{tabular}
         \caption{Table Caption}
         \end{table}
    \end{column}
    \hfill
    \begin{column}{5cm}
        \includegraphics[width=5cm]{}
        \includegraphics[width=5cm]{}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

**EDIT** If you only have a table and you want it left-aligned you can use the following *trick*. Maybe a better solution exists but this one seems to work, so...

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Results}
\begin{columns}[c]
    \begin{column}{5cm}
         \begin{table} 
         \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l}
             six & things & to & fill & the & space \\
         \end{tabular}
         \caption{Table Caption}
         \end{table}
    \end{column}
    \hspace{5cm}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solves my specific problem perfectly. One followup question: what if I had nothing else in my slide (i.e. no figures), and just wanted to left-align the table? Would you use two columns and just blank them? Or is there another command?

Comment: @putins See my edit

Comment: This solution is painful complicated.

Comment: This answer saved my! Thank you.